# conversion dictionary to specific format

Tags: python, dictionary

I have below dictionary

```
{1: [10], 2: [20, 30]}
```

and want to convert to like this below

```
{1:[{label:10,value:10}], 2:[{label:20,value:20}, {label:30,value:30}]}
```

Comment: your desired output is not valid dict literal. Also show what have you tried.

Comment: i need just that format not necessary dict literal

Comment: but it's not valid, names `label` and `value` are not defined. You probably want str `"label"` and `"value"`, but it's not clear. Also, you don't show any code of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although perl answer uses list comprehensions and its done on a single line, I don't think it achieves the format you wanted.
I, for myself, I couldnt do it using dict comprehension, so I could not do it in a single line but did dis:

```
old_dict = {1: [10], 2: [20, 30]}
new_dict = {}
for key, value in old_dict.items():
     new_dict[key] = [{"label":x, "value":x} for x in value]
```

And the output should be:

```
{1: [{'label': 10, 'value': 10}], 2: [{'label': 20, 'value': 20}, {'label': 30, 'value': 30}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
d = {1: [10], 2: [20, 30]}
{k: [{'label': v, 'value': v} for v in vs] for k, vs in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{1: [{'label': 10, 'value': 10}],
 2: [{'label': 20, 'value': 20}, {'label': 30, 'value': 30}]}
```